# Does there is a way to generate FCM token immediately?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM registration token taking 10 seconds to refresh and its very undesirable .How can i make it instant .I am Generating like this according to FCM Docs.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[FIRApp configure];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then,

```
- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

// Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.

[self connectToFcm];

}
```

And I Am using FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled.

Thanks in advance

Comment: consider of making it an asynchronous process, so users can proceed with the app without long waiting. then, upon receiving the token, you may process it accordingly (i.e. send to backend via API)

Answer (score 0):

The FCM tokens are generated asynchronously. There is no way to force them to be generated synchronously now. You'll have to wait for Firebase Cloud Messaging to call your `tokenRefreshNotification` callback.